# Is there a way to do SSH password-less login when the server only allows keyboard-interactive authentication?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

Suppose I've got a server `foo.com` which only allows keyboard-interactive authentication, and that I can't change this. This means I can do,

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh foo.com
```

but I can't create public/private keys to log in without a password.

If I want to automate getting to this server, i.e. ssh without password, I could just create an `alias ssh_foo="sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh foo.com"`, but then I have to create aliases for `scp`, for `sftp`, and in general it won't work for any other programs that use these, e.g. graphical programs based on `sftp` which mount remote folders. So I'm looking for a more generic solution.

In particular, is there any way to set up my `.ssh/config` file to allow password-less login in this case? This should then work for everything. I feel like some clever combination of `ProxyCommand` and `LocalCommand` might do it, but I can't figure out what.

(Note, I do understand the security implication of this, I'm just curious if you can do it)

Answer (score 1):

`ssh -p` is for specifying the remote port, SSH doesn't take passwords from the command line or from files.

The easiest way to achieve this is to multiplex the connection, login once with `ssh -fN` (which *might* be automatable by piping the password) which will create the control master, and use this connection to multiplex all others. Look at the `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` options in your friendly `man 5 ssh_config`.

Otherwise the use of a terminal manager *à la* `tmux`/`terminator` might be your only resort, but that would mandate wrapping all commands that rely on SSH.

Comment: Note it was `sshpass -p`, not `ssh -p`. But the `ControlMaster` is an interesting idea I hadn't thought of, thanks. I will play with it.